# Removing comma between numbers in CSV using regex in Sublime

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I'm very new to regex. Pardon me for silly questions.

I was wondering if it was possible to use regex pattern matcher to replace commas in between numbers such as, `$3,542` with `$3542` in **Sublime Editor**.

I tried to use `[0-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9]` to detect all such occurrences but don't know why I can't retain just numbers :/

Puzzled me!

Answer (score 5):

You may use capturing groups to retain digits:

```
(\$\d+),(\d+)
```

and replace with `$1$2`. You may remove `\$` if you do not care if it is a currency or not.

The `(\$\d+),(\d+)` regex  matches:

- `(\$\d+)` - Group 1 matching `$` as a literal symbol followed with 1 or more digits
- `,` - a literal comma
- `(\d+)` - Group 2 matching 1 or more digits

The `$1` and `$2` are backreferences that retrieve the texts stored in the memoru buffers for both groups.

[image]
                 /
[image]

Note that there are other ways to do the same, you can use lookarounds or a regex with `\K`, or using both, but capturing seems to me the most efficient solution for this case.

Comment: Slow connectivity :) ?

Comment: Change to lookarounds, and it will be a valid alternative. Or a version with `\K` - people love it.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>, select "regular expression" (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) and replace:

```
\$\d+\K,(?=\d)
```

with nothing.

---

Explanation:

`\$\d+\K` will match dollar sign followed by one or more digit (we use the `\K` - the short form of the positive lookbehind to do a zero-width assertion). The next token "," matches a comma and finally we use a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match digits.

Comment: Eh, I guess you still need the `\K`. Like `\$\d+\K,(?=\d)`. `(?<=\$\d),(?=\d+)` will not match `$12,235`

Comment: If the currency symbol is not important and removed from the regex pattern, the `(?<=\d),(?=\d)` regex might also work.